# При повороте экрана сбрасывается значение таймера, не могу понять что делаю не так

Tags: android

```
public class StopwatchActivity extends Activity {

private int seconds = 0;
private boolean running;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stopwatch);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        /*seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("second");
        running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");*/
        onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    runTimer();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("seconds", seconds);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("running", running);

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("second");
    running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");
}

public void onClickStart(View view) {
    running = true;
}

public void onClickStop(View view) {
    running = false;
}

public void onClickReset(View view) {
    running = false;
    seconds = 0;
}

private void runTimer() {

    final TextView timeView = findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int hours = seconds / 3600;
            int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
            int secs = seconds % 60;

            String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                    "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs);

            timeView.setText(time);
            if (running) seconds++;
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Добрый вечер, спасибо, но я и так тоже пробовал, все равно данные не   сохраняются. Секундомер сбрасывается на ноль, а переменная running в false. Прошелся дебаггером метод BaseBundle.getInt()  почему-то возвращает defaultValue для обоих переменных. то есть 0 и false...

Comment: Вы сохраняете под ключом `seconds` в `onSaveInstanceState`, а берёте ключ `second` в `onRestoreInstanceState`. Не в этом ли ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим в [доках](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=ru).

> Внимание! Реализацию суперкласса onSaveInstanceState() следует
>   вызывать во всех случаях, чтобы реализация по умолчанию могла
>   сохранить состояние новой иерархии.

1. Вы в `onSaveInstanceState` не вызвали суперкласс в конце метода

   ```
   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
   ```
2. Нельзя самому вызывать метод `onRestoreInstanceState`.
3. Вы либо сами в `onCreate` берёте `seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("second")`, либо берёте данные в `onRestoreInstanceState`.

P.S. вы сохраняете под ключом `seconds` в `onSaveInstanceState`, а берёте ключ `second` в `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось, действительно банальная невнимательность в наименовании ключа)).

Comment: @JohnDoe бывает ^_^